# Эквивалент /proc/somepid в Windows

Tags: linux, windows, shell, вывод

Я хочу перенаправить `STDOUT` одного процесса в другой.

В Linux я могу сделать так: `myprogram > /proc/1234/fd/1 &` (`1234` - любой PID)

Как это сделать в Windows?

Comment: в винде нет специальных "файлов-устройств" как в линуксе/юниксах, ну кроме LTP и COM1..9, через cmd такой трюк не выйдет. только через написание кода на чем нить еще. но опять же если процесс не твой, то это уже становится не так просто.

Comment: В винде есть специальные файлы-устройства и их немного больше чем COM/LPT и даже fd/1, но нет такого доступа к открытым дескрипторам другого процесса.